# displaying items from DB using Angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mongodb

the Item file

[image]

component file

[image]

the data service file

[image]

when I test my code with console log statements it says data from service is undefined

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Item } from '../item';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping-item',
  templateUrl: './shopping-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping-item.component.css'],
  providers: [DataService]

})
export class ShoppingItemComponent implements OnInit {
  shoppingItemList: Item[] = [];
  
  constructor(private dataservice: DataService){}

  getItems(){
    this.dataservice.getShoppingItems()
    .subscribe(items =>{
      this.shoppingItemList.push(items),
      console.log('data from dataservice '+ this.shoppingItemList[0].itemName);
    })
  }
  addItem(form: any){

    console.log(form)
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getItems();

  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use images for code/errors/backtraces/text output/etc. - just copy/paste the text into a codeblock.

Comment: @Citrine Welcome to SO, plz share code and not screenshots of code, also you have not shared how you can calling the service methods inside the component, are you sure the API is returning a value?

Comment: @NarenMurali i should have added it now in my latest edit please let me know if this is not what you needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are receiving an array from the API call, then you need to either assign it directly to the property (1) or destructure the array into the property (2)

Currently I guess you are pushing an array inside an array, which might lead to undefined error!

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Item } from '../item';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping-item',
  templateUrl: './shopping-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping-item.component.css'],
  providers: [DataService]

})
export class ShoppingItemComponent implements OnInit {
  shoppingItemList: Item[] = [];
  
  constructor(private dataservice: DataService){}

  getItems(){
    this.dataservice.getShoppingItems()
    .subscribe(items =>{
      this.shoppingItemList = items; // solution 1
      // this.shoppingItemList.push(...items); // solution 2
      console.log('data from dataservice '+ this.shoppingItemList[0].itemName);
    })
  }
  addItem(form: any){

    console.log(form)
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getItems();

  }
}
```

Comment: though the problem has been solved could you expand more on solution 2 because I am comparing it to my own code and I don't really understand how to destructure it completely?

Comment: @Citrine So when the items contains an array, we can use destructure it, by than I mean, take the individual elements of the array out of the array and you can supply it to push, which will push each element into the new array. you can also do the vice versa, where a list of params can be converted into an array,  example: function test(...args) {} <- in this, no matter how many params are passed to function test, it will get stored in the array args!